# Science of speculative biology

Tags: creature-design, xenobiology, bio-mechanics

My animal lives in planet full of rocks, so it evolved a drill-like mechanism in his hand. What material is that biological drill made of that crack granite like stones with ease ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Material for my animal's biological drill

Comment: How does its biological drill-like mechanism work?

Answer (score 2):

We also live on a planet full of rocks. Your animal would need to have a really good reason to do such a thing. And a lot of time!

Granite has a Mohs hardness of 6-7. So the material must be harder.

Diamond would have a hardness of 10. But how the hell could an animal evolve to have a diamond drill? Nobody would buy that.

Corundum (aluminium oxide) with a hardness of 9 looks like a good choice, because it is a common compound in nature. However, aluminium oxide does not dissolve in water. If the biology on your planet is water-based like ours your animal would have a hard time accumulating enough aluminium. There is a reason why aluminium plays no biological role on Earth despite its high abundance.

In fact aluminium oxide is not soluble in anything, so even if life on your planet is not water-based, that would not help. On your planet aluminium would have to occur in some other form, so that your animal can oxidize it in its body to form aluminium oxide by itself. But what could that be? In the solar system aluminium almost always occurs as oxide.

Maybe aluminium chloride (AlCl3) is a possibility. It occurs as rare mineral on Earth in hydrated form as AlCl(OH)2·4(H2O) and has good solubility in water. On your planet it could be a common mineral and could provide the aluminium cations for your animal to grow its drilling claw.

On the other hand, while corundum is hard, it is also a bit brittle, so it may get worn out quickly.

Humans use drills tipped with carbide to drill into granite.

Silicon carbide and boron carbide are almost as hard as diamond. Your animal could synthesize silicon carbide from silicic acid with the help of some weird unknown catalyst (humans produce it by reacting silicon and graphite at 2000°C). I do not know how realistic that is. Probably not much, but neither is your animal.

Another very hard substance is boron nitride (the hardest behind diamond I think), Humans produce it by reacting boron oxide with ammonia and it does not need as high temperatures as silicon carbide (1000°C or less) so it may be easier to synthesize by a biological entity. Boron would be easily available in a water based biochemistry.

Other choices would be titanium carbide and titanium diboride. They all have a hardness greater than 9.

Or maybe your animal has simply evolved to grow claws of steel hardened with carbon and alloyed with chromium. That should cut into most stones including granite.

I should point out though, nothing drills into granite "with ease".

On Earth no animals have evolved mobile parts as we use them in a machine. That's why there are no animals with wheels or drills. It seems to be something evolution cannot do easily despite having billions of years to try.

Answer (score 0):

## Tool use:

Even fairly primitive animals are capable of making some use of tools. Your species has evolved a rotational structure that allows drilling. That's pretty amazing, although on a microscopic scale, not unprecedented. So your species has an instinct to locate extremely hard rocks and use them as drill bits.

This allows your organism to still have the same basic biology we understand and still have amazingly hard bits for cutting rock.

Biologically there better be a huge payoff for such an energetic process, so consider that carefully. I would suggest a desirable prey species that hides in burrows, a plant species that grows into tiny holes and deposits calorically dense food under stone, or a significant need to make burrows in rock that are nearly invulnerable.